# Is it possible to repair this class to make it Immutable

Tags: java

I'm trying to repair the following class so it will become immutable:

```
public class ImmutableList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    private List<E> internal;
    public ImmutableList(List<E> l) {
        this.internal = l;
    }
    public int size() {
        return this.internal.size();
    }
    public E get(int i) {
        return this.internal.get(i);
    }
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return this.internal.iterator();
    }
}
```

but at the moment i'm not successful, my problem is that i don't know the type of E so i don't know how to deep copy it.
I wanted to know if it possible to make the class immutable?

thanks in advance

Comment: `new ArrayList<E>(l)`? Of course that still wouldn't make it immutable because `iterator()` can be used to mutate the underlying list but not knowing type `E` isn't an issue at all. But as for deep copying `E`, that isn't going to happen. With the defensive copy and the `iterator()` fix you can make your class conditionally immutable, the condition being that `E` has to be immutable too.

Comment: So if i understand it right i can "protect" the internal list, But i can't make the class completely immutable as long as i'm not sure rather E is immutable or not?

Comment: Correct. But that's beyond the control of your class and you shouldn't concern yourself with it. The important thing is that no-one can tamper with the internal state of your class that you can control.

Answer (score 3):

Your class is *nearly* "as immutable as possible."  There's no fully general way to deal with arbitrary generic types, so you should just not worry about it.

Two remaining issues:

- You need to copy `l` -- a shallow copy will suffice.  `this.internal = new ArrayList<E>(l)` will do.
- If `internal.iterator()` supports `remove()`, then consumers of your list type can remove elements.
- Make your class `final` so it cannot be subclassed in a mutable way.

Comment: Since the constructor doesn't make a defensive copy, it isn't anywhere near as immutable as possible.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be a final class? Otherwise I can, say, override the constructor, save `l` and it will be mutable again.